# ZK java null pointer exception in controller

Tags: java, zk

i got some error when deploying ZK

```
Jan 16, 2012 5:00:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [zkLoader] in context with path [/ZK509App6] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.jurnal.JournalController.<init>(JournalController.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
```

**here's my JournalController.java class**

```
public class JournalController extends GenericForwardComposer {

    private Listbox listlk;
    private Datebox datebox;
    private koneksi k;
    private Connection c;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    private Button pilih;
    private Date dates;
    private jurnalDAO jd = new jurnalDAO(k.getConnection(), dates);


    public JournalController() {
    }

    public void onClick$pilih(Event e) throws Exception, SQLException {
        try {
            Date d = datebox.getValue();
            d = dates;
            ForwardEvent forwardEvt = (ForwardEvent) e;
            Listbox Listlk = (Listbox) forwardEvt.getOrigin().getTarget();
        } catch (Exception a) {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public List<Jurnal_tbl> getAllEvents() throws SQLException, Exception {

        return jd.getLKeuangan();
    }
}
```

**the line of (JournalController.java:39) is
private jurnalDAO jd = new jurnalDAO(k.getConnection(), dates);**

**for refrences, this is DAO Class**

```
public class jurnalDAO {

    private Connection conn;
    private Date tanggal;

    public jurnalDAO(Connection conn, Date dates) {
        this.conn = conn;
        this.tanggal = dates;
    }


    public List<Jurnal_tbl> getLKeuangan() throws SQLException, Exception {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            List<Jurnal_tbl> llk = new ArrayList<Jurnal_tbl>();
            System.out.println("test1");


            String sql = "SELECT * from public.jurnal where tanggal = ?";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(tanggal.getTime()));
            System.out.println(ps.toString());;

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            Jurnal_tbl jt;
            while (rs.next()) {
                // llk.add(new Jurnal_tbl(rs.getString("kd_jurnal"), rs.getString("no_trans"), rs.getString("tanggal"), rs.getString("account"), rs.getString("descript"), rs.getString("dc"), rs.getDouble("amount"), rs.getString("no_item")));
                jt = new Jurnal_tbl();
                jt.setKode(rs.getString("kd_jurnal"));
                jt.setTransaksi(rs.getString("no_trans"));
                jt.setTanggal(rs.getString("tanggal"));
                jt.setAkun(rs.getString("akun"));
                jt.setDeskripsi(rs.getString("descript"));
                jt.setDC(rs.getString("dc"));
                jt.setAmount(rs.getDouble("amount"));
                jt.setItem(rs.getString("no_item"));
                llk.add(jt);
           }

            rs.close();
            return llk;
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```

please help me guys T.T
this is my final project of my bachelor deegres T.T

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `k.getConnection()`, but you've never initialized `k` so it will have the default value of `null`. That's bound to throw `NullPointerException`. What object did you *expect* it to be calling `getConnection()` on?

As a side-note, it's worth paying attention to names:

- `k` is a pretty meaningless name for an instance variable
- You're inconsistent between "journal" and "jurnal"
- The type name `koneksi` doesn't follow Java naming conventions (capitalization)
- The variable name `Listlk` doesn't follow Java naming conventions (capitalization)
- The type name `Jurnal_tbl` doesn't follow Java naming conventions (underscore)

Additionally:

- You should almost never catch `Exception`
- You should close resources in `finally` blocks

(I haven't done a thorough analysis of the code - that's just my initial impressions.)

Comment: :i have initialized k variable, in the third line.
`private koneksi k;`

is it wrong?

Comment: @aulia: That's *declared* the variable, but it will have its initial value of `null`. If you hadn't even declared it, you'd have got a compile-time error rather than an execution-time exception...

Comment: Another remark: You should not use `$` in method names like you are doing in `onClick$pilih`. It's not an illegal character, but it is more or less reserved for the compiler (for automatically-generated names).

Comment: @Jesper , the $ naming is a convention in ZK GenericForwardComposer .

Comment: thanks all for answered,
@jesper: i have read the documention about button, $ is a declared function to called button id. im not sure about it, as far as i read :D